# Binding datagrid control to Linq to entity query result

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

I am new to WPF and entity framework. In my application I want to do something very simple, display the  the result of following linq to query result in a datagrid.
here is my query

C#

```
private void applyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string classFilter = classNameTextBox.Text;
        var result = from c in partNumberContext.PartClasses
                     where c.chrPCName == classFilter                         
                     select c;            

    }
```

here is my XML

```
<Window x:Class="Engenious.PartNumbers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Part Details" Height="377" Width="607" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PartClassSource" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Height="346" Width="590">

    <Label Content="Class Filter" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,26,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,28,141,0" Name="classNameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Content="Apply" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,27,26,0" Name="applyButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="applyButton_Click" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="263" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,71,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Solved it. Just set  dataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the AutoGenerateColumns in datagrid to true.

Here is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="Engenious.PartNumbers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Part Details" Height="377" Width="607" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="PartClassSource" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Height="346" Width="590">

    <Label Content="Class Filter" Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,26,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,28,141,0" Name="classNameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Content="Apply" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,27,26,0" Name="applyButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="applyButton_Click" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" Height="263" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,71,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479"  />
</Grid>
```